# Netlift build: gatsby-source-prismic - Invalid plugin options | Environment variables in Netlify

Tags: graphql, gatsby, netlify, prismic.io

When I try to deploy my Gatsby Site on Netlify, it stops deploying and throws the error `gatsby-source-prismic - invalid plugin options`

Local it builds perfect and I have no issues, I added a `.env` file with `PRISMIC_REPOSITORY_NAME` and `PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN` with the values from Prismic.io.

My plugin options are:

```
      resolve: `gatsby-source-prismic`,
      options: {
        repositoryName: process.env.PRISMIC_REPOSITORY_NAME,
        accessToken: process.env.PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        schemas: {
          post: require("./src/schemas/articles.json"),
        },
      },
    },
```

The Stack:

```
10:32:38 PM: Failed to validate error Error [ValidationError]: child "type" fails because ["type" must be one of [GRAPHQL, CONFIG, WEBPACK, PLUGIN]]
10:32:38 PM:     at Object.exports.process (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/errors.js:202:19)
10:32:38 PM:     at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:763:31)
10:32:38 PM:     at internals.Object.validate (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:797:21)
10:32:38 PM:     at constructError (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/structured-errors/construct-error.js:52:32)
10:32:38 PM:     at Reporter.error (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/reporter.js:135:59)
10:32:38 PM:     at Reporter.panic (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/reporter.js:75:34)
10:32:38 PM:     at Object.webhookBody [as panic] (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:201:16)
10:32:38 PM:     at Object.exports.sourceNodes (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-source-prismic/src/gatsby-node.ts:160:8)
10:32:38 PM:     at runAPI (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:460:22)
10:32:38 PM:     at Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:611:13)
10:32:38 PM:     at Promise._execute (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
10:32:38 PM:     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
10:32:38 PM:     at new Promise (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)
10:32:38 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:609:16
10:32:38 PM:     at tryCatcher (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
10:32:38 PM:     at Object.gotValue (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:166:18) {
10:32:38 PM:   isJoi: true,
10:32:38 PM:   details: [
10:32:38 PM:     {
10:32:38 PM:       message: '"type" must be one of [GRAPHQL, CONFIG, WEBPACK, PLUGIN]',
10:32:38 PM:       path: [Array],
10:32:38 PM:       type: 'any.allowOnly',
10:32:38 PM:       context: [Object]
10:32:38 PM:     }
10:32:38 PM:   ],
10:32:38 PM:   _object: {
10:32:38 PM:     context: {},
10:32:38 PM:     value: undefined,
10:32:38 PM:     type: 'string',
10:32:38 PM:     path: [],
10:32:38 PM:     branch: [ undefined ],
10:32:38 PM:     failures: [Function: failures],
10:32:38 PM:     pluginName: 'gatsby-source-prismic',
10:32:38 PM:     text: 'There was an error',
10:32:38 PM:     level: 'ERROR',
10:32:38 PM:     stack: [],
10:32:38 PM:     docsUrl: 'https://gatsby.dev/issue-how-to'
10:32:38 PM:   },
10:32:38 PM:   annotate: [Function]
10:32:38 PM: }
10:32:38 PM: not finished source and transform nodes - 0.127s
10:32:38 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I hope some one can help me out with this. I don`t know what the mistake is.

Comment: Can you add more details? Are you setting properly your `.env` in Netlify? Does it build locally? etc

Comment: Sorry thats my fault, yes it builds  fine localy and i added a `.env` file with "PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN" and "PRISMIC_REPOSITORY_NAME"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with environment variables with Gatsby + Netlify, you have to prefix them with `GATSBY_` to make them available to Netlify. So:

```
PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN
PRISMIC_REPOSITORY_NAME
```

Will become:

```
GATSBY_PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN
GATSBY_PRISMIC_REPOSITORY_NAME
```

Change them locally in your `.env` files and on Netlify's side by:

[image: Environment variables in Netlify]

*Note: you can access that configuration in [https://app.netlify.com/sites/[YOUR_PROJECT]/settings/deploys#environment](https://app.netlify.com/sites/%5BYOUR_PROJECT%5D/settings/deploys#environment)*

Resources:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/
- https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-a-react-component/1635

Comment: thanks so much, this solved my problems with deploying